# Perl: grep unique value from a variable

Tags: perl

I am using XML::Simple to parse a xml file.

```
my $servers = XMLin('file.xml');
for my $server (@{$servers->{server}}) {
    my %seen  = ();
    my $node =  $server->{NodeName} . "\n";
    my $lanip = $server->{LanIP} . "\n";
    my $mask = $server->{Netmask} . "\n";

    substr($lanip, 11, 3) = "0";
    print "$lanip\n";
}
```

The output here is like below

```
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.32.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.32.0
192.169.32.0
```

Here I only want to grep unique values but I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.

I have used below methods

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my @unique = uniq $lanip;
```

also this

```
my @unique = do { my %seen; grep { !$seen{$_}++ } $lanip };
```

also this

```
print $lanip . "\n" if !  $seen{$lanip}++
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Is `$lanip` a string that contains all the IPs? It is not clear from you question. I assumed that it is but according to the code example it seems to contain a single IP.

Comment: You should use `uniq` on an array, not a string. For example: `perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -E '@a=qw(192.169.30.0 192.169.30.0 192.169.31.0); say $_ for uniq @a;'`

Comment: Your last attempt should work if `%seen` is declared outside of the loop: `my %seen; for my $server (@{$servers->{server}}) { ...`

Comment: `@melpomene` - I tried that but unfortunately doesn't works either

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use XML::Simple;

my $servers = XMLin('network.xml');
my %seen ;
foreach my $server (@{$servers->{server}}) {
    my %seen ;
    my $node =  $server->{NodeName__1} . "\n";
    my $lanip = $server->{CoreLanIP_1__1};
    my $mask = $server->{CoreLanNetmask_1} . "\n";

    substr($lanip, 11, 3) = "0";
   print $lanip . "\n" if !  $seen{$lanip}++;
}`

Comment: @user55342 You have `my %seen;` twice in there (the outer one being unused because of shadowing). Remove the inner declaration.

Comment: Please give some sample XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use hash map to find unique values:

```
#Let's count how many times each ip occures in a list    
%ip_count;
for $ip (@ips) {
  if (not defined $ip_count{$ip}) {
    $ip_count{$ip} = 1;
  }
  else {
    $ip_count{$ip}++;
  }
}

# Now we need to filter unique ips
@unique_ips;
for $ip (keys(%ip_count)) {
  if ($ip_count{$ip} == 1) {
    push(@unique_ips, $ip);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of those work since `$lanip` is a scalar variable and not a list. You'd need to convert it into a list first:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my $lanip="192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.30.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.31.0
192.169.32.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.72.0
192.169.32.0
192.169.32.0";

my @unique=uniq split(/\n/,$lanip);
print "@unique\n";
```

Or, to print each unique IP on a separate line:

```
print join "\n", @unique , "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please please please - don't use `XML::Simple`. Even it's docs suggests not using it.

Also - you *look* like you're converting your IP address to a network address by just sticking a zero as the last octet. That *only* works if you're using `/24` subnets, so really - you shouldn't do that.

Something like `Net::IPv4Addr` looks like it does that sum for you, giving you a *proper* address range. (Or you can do bit patterns yourself if you're so inclined - all you're doing is logical AND of the bit mask and IP address. )

Instead - guessing a bit on your XML structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my %seen;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'file.xml' ); 
foreach my $server ( $twig -> findnodes ('//server') ) {
    my $lanip = $server->first_child_text('LanIP');
    my $mask = $server->first_child_text('Netmask'); 
    my ($net) = Net::IPv4Addr::ipv4_network( "$lanip/$mask" 
    $seen{$net}++; 
}

print join ( "\n", sort keys %seen );
```